# Convert isf format to png?

Tags: c#, image, .net-4.0

I need to convert isf file to png format in winform and i could use net framework 4 only ,
i couldn't use version above it.
Is it possible?

Comment: What is `isf`? It's *not* a common image format. And what does `i could use net framework 4 only` mean? .NET Framework 4.x versions are binary replacements which means that unless you target Windows XP, you'll always run on a newer version, simply because it got upgraded by Windows Update sometime in the last 7 years.

Comment: isf format is a vector image format that uses for digital pen and microsoft.ink ,we have limitation for NET Framework because of our customers.

Comment: That doesn't say anything - in fact, googling for `isf` returns hits for a flowchart and waveform file format. You're using an even rarer format. Which application creates it? Did you check the vendor's site? Do they have any libraries that can read that format or render it?

Comment: And again, what does `i could use net framework 4 only` mean? Have you found a library for old .NET Framework versions?

Comment: Is it [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ink_Serialized_Format) that you're referring to? If so, the Wiki page links to the format's [specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/InkSerializedFormat(ISF)Specification.pdf).

Comment: I see this method in wpf : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a583fa9d-ea2b-4d1a-99e1-9cb039f7637d/how-to-convert-isf-to-png?forum=wpf     ,it could be use in winform ,but needs NET Framework 4.6.2 that we couldn't use.

Comment: @AliRad that's a discussion in a forum, not a method n WPF. It was posted in 2010 anyway and refers to .NET 4.0, not 4.6.2. .NET 4.5 came out in 2012. What's the problem with this code?

Comment: In  discussion a method suggested that uses InkCanvas in wpf , i test it and it is OK , but if i want to use it in winform  i need NET Framework 4.6.2  to use wpf features in winform .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used wpf to convert isf to png.
I create a wpf userControl and convert isf to png as described in following link forum:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a583fa9d-ea2b-4d1a-99e1-9cb039f7637d/how-to-convert-isf-to-png?forum=wpf
At the end i add control library to winform ,thanks for comments.